# Segmentation Fault error on executing opencv code

Tags: opencv

I am running opencv sample code on arm-linux-gnuabi
, It complies fine,I have installed `opencv` on`Pandaboard` `arm-linux` following this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/andrewssobral/pandaboard).I used `gdb` debugger for debugging, On executing It with `gdb` throws an error

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/Desktop/pkgs/project/main
Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled

program received signal SIGSEGV Segmentation fault.
0x41ab1582 in sincosl () from /lib/arm-linux-gnuabi/libm.so.6
```

I am not using any cross compiling environment.
Here is the code:

```
Test OpenCV with this example code (copy and paste in main.cpp file):
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
#include < stdio.h >
#include < cv.h >
#include < highgui.h >

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
CvCapture *capture = 0;
IplImage *frame = 0;
int key = 0;

capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

if(!capture)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open initialize webcam!\n");
return 1;
}

cvNamedWindow("result");

while(key != 'q')
{
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

if(!frame) break;

cvShowImage("result", frame);

key = cvWaitKey(1);
}

cvDestroyWindow("result");
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

return 0;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
Compile and run:
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --libs opencv`
./main
```

Thanks

Comment: add a language tag - your code looks like C, however you invoked `g++` to compile it.

Comment: Yes code is in C, but it compiles using g++ compiler. This is not causing any problem. I used g++ compiler many times to compile my C code on linux system.

Comment: If it is compiled using a g++ compiler, then it is actually C++ code. C and C++ are different languages . This question should be tagged `c++` accordingly. If you have C code then compile it with `gcc`.

Comment: try using your debugger to see which cv function this error is occurring in.

Comment: "Yes code is in C" - please don't use opencv's deprecated c-api. they did away with it in 2010 in favour of a c++ api, please use that instead.

Comment: code is compiled fine, but I found segmentation fault error at this code : `capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);`